# Oracle Service Bus: business service gives transfer-encoding as 'chunked' , even though 'Use chunked streaming mode' is disabled

Tags: httpresponse, oracle12c, weblogic12c, osb, transfer-encoding

Business service gives transfer-encoding as 'chunked' even though the 'use chunked streaming mode' is disabled in the http Transport configuration.

As part of one of our requirements we need the content-length in the http response header ,  since the service response is getting chunked by default , the content-length is ignored in the header.

This is observed in OSB 12c versions ( tested in 12.1.3 and 12.2.1.2).

Kindly help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Setting transfer-encoding as 'chunked' in OSB HTTP business Service only gurantees the request is chunked. It doesn't say about the response .

If the client is using HTTP /1.1 protocol most of the response is chuncked .